# openURL function is not call when application in inactive/Terminated

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, url-scheme

I am using `URL Scheme` in my application and for this i am using:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL,  sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    print("function called")
    return true
}
```

it working fine when application is in `Background` But when i hit a URL and application is `Inactive` state or application is not running thn this function is not called

Need help to hit this function when application is `Terminated`.
If Can't Then can we have any alternative ?

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work for you when app is terminated. It works well for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of cause you can....

Get URL from "launchOptions" in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions with key "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey"

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.url] as? URL {
    // do your thing...
}
```

Comment: im not getting the url in launch options, app opens but it doesnt go inside the if let url block/